What are the footprint dimensions for a GX-16 8-pin ("aviation") connector?
I would like to make through-holes in a PCB to mount a GX16 8-pin connector. I have looked everywhere but cannot find a source for the pin dimensions---and they are not consistent.  I've measured with callipers, and I can probably mock something up, but I would really like an authoritative source, or at least an image with dimension markers.
At first glance it looks like it is 7 pins equally distributed around a center, but that isn't the case.  The two pins nearest the key are slightly farther apart and the remaining pins appear to be similar if not the same.
I've found (at least) two 3D-modeled GX16-8 examples here, but the measurements don't agree closely enough to the one I have measured with calipers to say that the model is correct.
Anyway, I can guess-and-check with calipers, but would like real dimensions to build a footprint with.  Pics:
Rear
This is what I would like to PCB mount:

Front of connector (male)
This is the mating connector.  They are commonly used on radios for radio mic inputs:

Female mating connector:

[ image source ]

It looks like the first connector you show is intended to be mounted to a panel, then have wires soldered into the pins, rather than being mounted directly to a PCB.

They are solder cup and not intended for PCB-mount. The actual pin positions and other specs (though possibly not the solder cup dimensions) are probably squirreled away in some military specification, as the US  38999 style connectors are.

@SpehroPefhany hm, Wikipedia says "…Chinese mainland and Taiwan manufacturers adopted this connector as the GX16 (16 mm) for power and avionics usage" from a microphone connector. So probably not a western military standard!

Hey, do you have the female connector, and a flatbet scanner, and a ruler or scale/graph paper with known-dimension markings? Scan, find centre of holes, use reference ruler/paper to derive dimensions in mm. Note that if wikipedia is right, then the mating tolerances on these things are probably relatively high, so what's 0.1mm among friends…

if this can help https://www.sunrom.com/download/663.pdf

@Antonio51 not really, it's a derivative, probably copied from the competition, highly compressed JPEG of the connector arrangement, not a dimensional drawing

@MarcusMüller Oh, I didn't say it was a Western standard... I would expect it's a Chinese standard. Like all those relays that have similar part numbers from different makers.

@Antonio51, thanks, I found that on etoo.  It gives outer dims, but no pin-to-pin dims.

The connector is intended to have wires soldered to it.
It is not intended for soldering those pins directly to PCB.
Therefore, as it is not a PCB-mountable connector, it has no defined PCB land pattern, and the terminals with the solder cups can be technically of any shape and structure.
You can of course still do it, but you may run into mechanical issues. For example as there is no other mechanical support for soldering the connector and thus all the strain between connector chassis and the PCB will be on the solder cup electrical contacts not intended to have mechanical strain.
Now I don't know the construction of that specific connector, but for example some solder cup receptacles have contacts that wiggle a bit loose so they are allowed to adjust their orientation (angle and position) slighty when plug pins are inserted into receptacle pins. If your connector is like this, by soldering the solder cup terminals directly to PCB will prevent this auto aligning and the pins may just get fixed into difficult orientation so plugging in is difficult and causes additional strain to the terminals and solder joint.
It looks like the receptacle has the pins fixed and the plug on the cable has the moving sockets.

Thanks for the detailed answer.  Regarding "...have contacts that wiggle a bit loose...", it is solid epoxy, and I'd still plan to use the bulkhead screw for chassis stability.  I know it is not meant for PCB mounting, but thought it would be easier to drop it into a small mouse-bite-break-off "connector board" with a 90-degree B2B connector to the mainboard to minimize hand soldering.  This isn't volume production, so I can hand solder the pins...I dislike cup-soldering and thought a through-hole footprint might be a nice work-around to quickly solder the pins to a board.

As I commented above, you can build an approximate footprint when you have the female connector, and a flatbet scanner, and a ruler or scale/graph paper with known-dimension markings. Scan, find centre of holes, use reference ruler/paper to derive dimensions in mm. Note that if wikipedia is right, then the mating tolerances on these things are probably relatively high.
As Justme points out, at least one side hence has to be slightly flexible with its pin positions/angles. If it happens to be the side you want to connect to your board: don't do it rigidly. Frankly, an 8-conductor board-to-wire connector, and soldering these 8 connectors to your male connector, which looks designed for panel mount, looks like the safer alternative, and might turn out to be less work. If, for spatial reasons, you really need to mount this thing millimeters above your PCB: board cutout (one large circle to let all pins through), and soldering "jumpers" from on-board contacts arranged around that hole (or proper wire-to-board contacting/connectors again).

Great idea on the scanner.  I know the scanner's DPI, so pixel counts give me the layout!

See the answer below, the result of your scanning idea.  Thanks again.

Thanks to @MarcusMüller for the scanning idea.  Read the other answers, too, they have good points about potential mechanical issues.
The results below agree with caliper measurements.  I've seen others asking about this in other forums, so here they are for the next person.
Note that these are the female measurements, so flip it left-to-right for male:
1. Center of the center pin is the datum (0,0):
First, I scanned the image, squared it up manually, and sampled X,Y pairs from pin-centers with Gimp's box select (because it gives a pixel range selection).  Then raw pixel positions are converted to mm from 600dpi points:

2. Caliper validation of distances to the next pin:
This section averages the pixel-to-pixel differences and validates with calipers.  Pin-to-pin on the outer ring is very close to the measured values. Note that the pin-to-pin distance around the key between pins 1-7 is different, but correct:

3. Distances to center pin:
These are difficult to measure with calipers, so there may be a greater measurement error.  Still, the error column is pretty small:

I was surprised to get ~0.1mm resolution from a scan, it turned out pretty well.  Now, was this less work than just soldering the cups with a jumper wire?  Not sure, but hey, it was fun, and now I have a new footprint-capture technique. ;)  Thanks everyone for your suggestions and ideas.
Here is the original 600 DPI scan, laying flat on the glass:


Really, really Nice Work!

I love how differently this scan is from the diagram on the catalog pages, where pins 3 and 4 are much closer together, and pin 2 seems to be further away from the origin than the others.
